# Entire function $f(\log{k})=\frac{1}{1+\log{k}}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: complex-analysis

This problem appears on the written exam for Complex Analysis.

Can we find an entire function f with $f(\log{k})=\frac{1}{1+\log{k}}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$? If the answer to previous question is positive, then can such $f$ satisfy $|f(z)|\leq c \exp(|z|^\alpha)$ for some positive constants $c$ and $\alpha$?

I have no idea how to do it.

Comment: For the first part: if $x_n$ and $y_n$ are sequences of complex numbers such that $x_n$ has no limit point, there is an entire function with $f(x_n) = y_n$.

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh, wow. Never heard of this result. Can you quote it? Is it related to Wierestrass theorem?

Comment: Corollary of Mittag-Leffler's theorem and the Weierstrass factorization theorem.  Or see [this paper](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2370666).

Answer (score 1):

For the second part, $f$ is to be an entire function of finite order $\alpha$.
Now you want $f(\log k) = \dfrac{1}{1+\log k}$,
i.e. $h(z) = (1 + z) f(z) - 1$, which is again an entire function of order $\alpha$, 
is to have zeros $\log k$.  But since for all positive integers $m$,
$$\sum_{k=2}^\infty |\log k|^{-m} = \infty$$
such a function can't have finite rank.  Thus this would contradict the [Hadamard factorization theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/HadamardFactorizationTheorem.html).